# display name on html page by clicking on button. The button is generated using data from database

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a button that is generated using the database information. For example if I insert a name "john" with age 15 into the database, a button with the text "john" along with his age will be generated onto the html page. This is done using appendData function and the buttons are displayed by looping through the data and appending it onto the html page.

I want it as such that if I click on the button with the text "john" I will be displayed the word "john" and 15 on the side.

I tried sending data[i] but its not working. Can someone please help? thank you

```
<div id="myData" ></div>
    <aside>
        <p>Details: </p>
        <p id="configurationdetails"></p>
    </aside>

<script>
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/result')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });
        function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");

                div.innerHTML = '<div class="container"> <div class="solid"> <button id="btn" class="btn" onclick="showinfo('+data[i]+')">' + 'name '+data[i].person_name +data[i].age+  '</button> </div></div>';
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
        }

        function showinfo(info) {
  document.getElementById("configurationdetails").innerHTML = info;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to fix it is to not pass the object, but just the value `i` in the showInfo function:

```
data = [{person_name:"henk", age:33}, {person_name:"wim", age:34}]

appendData(data)

function appendData(data) {
  // save data for later
  window.data = data

  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<div class="container"> <div class="solid"> <button id="btn" class="btn" onclick="showinfo('+i+')">' + 'name '+data[i].person_name +data[i].age+  '</button> </div></div>';
    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
  }
}

function showinfo(i) {
  document.getElementById("configurationdetails").innerHTML = data[i].person_name + " " + data[i].age;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it doesnt work for me unfortunately. I tried clicking on the button but nothing appears in the div

Comment: You can see that it works at this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3rukaz91/1/ . Is there something different in your code?

Comment: I have a fetch that gets info from sql database. I tried comparing our codes and the only time the error appears is when i change the data = [{person_name:"henk", age:33}, {person_name:"wim", age:34}] with the fetch to get data

Comment: You probably don't wait for the fetch to finish? You'll have to include the fetch code in your question, else it's hard to see what you're missing.

Comment: I think you don't save the `data` globally, so in the `showInfo` function the data is not found. You can fix it by "saving" the data in the global scope at the start of `appendData`

Answer (score 0):

i just created ectra div with id "contentFromUrl" when the page first load and call api so it fills the data in div and when button click it again fetch fills the data.

i provided two cases which one you like you can choose!

```
<div id="myData" ></div>
<div id="contentFromUrl"></div>
    <aside>
        <p>Details: </p>
        <p id="configurationdetails"></p>
    </aside>

<script>
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/result')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });
        function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");

                div.innerHTML = '<div class="container"> <div class="solid"> <button id="btn" class="btn" onclick="showinfo('+data[i]+')">' + 'name '+data[i].person_name +data[i].age+  '</button> </div></div>';
                document.getElementById("contentFromUrl").innerHTML = data[i].person_name +data[i].age;
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
        }

        function showinfo(info) {
  document.getElementById("configurationdetails").innerHTML = info;
  document.getElementById("contentFromUrl").innerHTML = info.person_name + info.age;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but nothing shows up when i click on the button